# output differences between 2 texts when lines are dissimilar

Tags: python, difflib

I am relatively new to Python so apologies in advance for sounding a bit ditzy sometimes. I'll try took google and attempt your tips as much as I can before asking even more questions.
Here is my situation: I am working with R and stylometry to find out the (likely) authorship of a text. What I'd like to do is see if there is a difference in the stylometry of a novel in the second edition, after one of the (assumed) co-authors died and therefore could not have contributed. In order to research that I need

- Text edition 1
- Text edition 2

and for python to output

- words that appear in text 1 but not in text 2
- words that appear in text 2 but not in text 1

And I would like to have the words each time they appear so not just 'the' once, but every time the program encounters it when it differs from the first edition (yep I know I'm asking for a lot sorry)

I have tried approaching this via

```
file1 = open("FRANKENST18.txt", "r")
file2 = open("FRANKENST31.txt", "r")
file3 = open("frankoutput.txt", "w")
list1 = file1.readlines()
list2 = file2.readlines()
file3.write("here: \n")
for i in list1:
    for j in list2:
        if  i==j:
            file3.write(i)
```

but of course this doesn't work because the texts are two giant balls of texts and not separate lines that can be compared, plus the first text has far more lines than the second one. Is there a way to go from lines to 'words' or the text in general to overcome that? Can I put an entire novel in a string lol? I assume not.
I have also attempted to use difflib, but I've only started coding a few weeks ago and I find it quite complicated. For example, I used fraxel's script as a base for:

```
from difflib import Differ

s1 = open("FRANKENST18.txt", "r")
s1 = open("FRANKENST31.txt", "r")

def appendBoldChanges(s1, s2):
#"Adds <b></b> tags to words that are changed"
    l1 = s1.split(' ')
    l2 = s2.split(' ')
dif = list(Differ().compare(l1, l2))
return " ".join(['<b>'+i[2:]+'</b>' if i[:1] == '+' else i[2:] for i in dif 
                                                       if not i[:1] in '-?'])

print appendBoldChanges
```

but I couldn't get it to work.

So my question is is there any way to output the differences between texts that are not similar in lines like this? It sounded quite do-able but I've greatly underestimated how difficult I found Python haha.
Thanks for reading, any help is appreciated!

EDIT: posting my current code just in case it might help fellow learners that are googling for answers:

```
file1 = open("1stein.txt")
originaltext1 = file1.read()
wordlist1={}

import string
text1 = [x.strip(string.punctuation) for x in originaltext1.split()]
text1 = [x.lower() for x in text1]

for word1 in text1:
    if word1 not in wordlist1:
        wordlist1[word1] = 1
    else:
        wordlist1[word1] += 1

for k,v in sorted(wordlist1.items()):
    #print "%s %s" % (k, v)
    col1 = ("%s %s" % (k, v))
    print col1

file2 = open("2stein.txt")
originaltext2 = file2.read()
wordlist2={}

import string
text2 = [x.strip(string.punctuation) for x in originaltext2.split()]
text2 = [x.lower() for x in text2]

for word2 in text2:
    if word2 not in wordlist2:
        wordlist2[word2] = 1
    else:
        wordlist2[word2] += 1

for k,v in sorted(wordlist2.items()):
    #print "%s %s" % (k, v)
    col2 = ("%s %s" % (k, v))
    print col2
```

what I hope still to edit and output is something like this:
using the dictionaries' key and value system (applied to col1 and col2): {apple 3, bridge 7, chair 5} - {apple 1, bridge 9, chair 5} = {apple 2, bridge -2, chair 5}?

Comment: ["Can Someone Help Me?" is not a valid SO question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question).  This usually suggests that what you need is half an hour with a local tutor or walk through a tutorial, rather than Stack Overflow.  In particular, you need to spend some time with string and text processing.  Use `split` to divide lines into words; use sets and set difference to get the word lists you need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to output:

- words that appear in text 1 but not in text 2
- words that appear in
  text 2 but not in text 1

Interesting. A set difference is what you need.

```
import re
s1 = open("FRANKENST18.txt", "r").read()
s1 = open("FRANKENST31.txt", "r").read()

words_s1 = re.findall("[A-Za-z]",s1)
words_s2 = re.findall("[A-Za-z]",s2)

set_s1 = set(words_s1)
set_s2 = set(words_s2)

words_in_s1_but_not_in_s2 = set_s1 - set_s2
words_in_s2_but_not_in_s1 = set_s2 - set_s1

words_in_s1 = '\n'.join(words_in_s1_but_not_in_s2)
words_in_s2 = '\n'.join(words_in_s2_but_not_in_s1)

with open("s1_output","w") as s1_output:
    s1_output.write(words_in_s1)

with open("s2_output","w") as s2_output:
    s2_output.write(words_in_s2)
```

Comment: Hi Saikat, you are a life saver, thank you very much! I was so happy that you showed me how to get output files - this is exactly what I need. So far they are empty, but tomorrow I will continue working on it. Again thank you very much

Comment: you are welcome. would you mind [accepting](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) this answer? :-)

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I now have two lists with words and their number of occurences. Can I also perform an action similar like "words_in_s1_but_not_in_s2 = set_s1 - set_s2
words_in_s2_but_not_in_s1 = set_s2 - set_s1" on these dictionaries? That would give me something like {apple 3, bridge 7, chair 5} - {apple 1, bridge 9, chair 5} = {apple 2, bridge -2, chair 5}?

Comment: Given x & y are your dictionaries and you want to subtract occurrences of items in y from items in x:

`{k1: v1-y.get(k1,0) for k1,v1 in x.items() }`

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this isn't exactly what you're looking for, but it seems like you want to iterate through lines of a file, which you can do very easily in python. Here's an example, where I omit the newline character at the end of each line, and add the lines to a list:

```
f = open("filename.txt", 'r')
lines = []
for line in f:
    lines.append(f[:-1])
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hi Cary, thanks, that helped a lot! I managed to iterate through it like you said. Now I'm working on getting the list to work, not quite there yet but the idea helps a lot!

Comment: What issues are you having with the list?

Comment: Hi Cary, I did not manage to append the words at first, but that turned out to be because I confused lines and words (and how to append to dictionaries)

Comment: Good to hear. Did you get everything sorted out?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not completely sure if you're trying to compare the differences in words as they occur or lines as they occur, however one way you could do this is by using a dictionary. If you want to see which lines change you could split the lines on periods by doing something like:

```
text = 'this is a sentence. this is another sentence.'
sentences = text.split('.')
```

This will split the string you have (which contains the entire text I assume) on the periods and will return an array (or list) of all the sentences.

You can then create a dictionary with `dict = {}`, loop over each sentence in the previously created array, make it a key in the dictionary with a corresponding value (could be anything since most sentences probably don't occur more than once). After doing this for the first version you can go through the second version and check which sentences are the same. Here is some code that will give you a start (assuming version1 contains all the sentences from the first version):

```
for sentence in version1:
    dict[sentence] = 1                     #put a counter for e
```

You can then loop over the second version and check if the same sentence is found in the first, with something like:

```
  for sentence in version2:
       if sentence in dict:            #if the sentence is in the dictionary
            pass
            #or do whatever you want here
       else:                           #if the sentence isn't
            print(sentence)
```

Again not sure if this is what you're looking for but hope it helps

Comment: Hello Pine Fresh, thank you very much! That helped me tremendously. Now I can visualise what I am doing. I'm still struggling with a few errors because apparently the 'integer' is not defined, but I got some output on a small test file and I will try to implement your method. You're the best!

Comment: I'm glad you found this helpful, what errors are you receiving?

Comment: Hello Pine Fresh, just wanted to say thanks again. I managed to count all the words and the times they appeared due to your help here. The error I receive is not really an error but mainly the difficulty for me to compare the keys and values once they are in the dictionary. I have a dictionary with "yours 1
yourself 28
yourselves 1
youth 11" and a dictionary with "yours 4
yourself 28
yourselves 1
youth 21" and would like to output a list with the differences. That's what I'm working on (and failing haha) right now.

Comment: Upon looking at your updated question I think what you need to do is create a third dictionary to store the difference. Assuming `d1` and `d2` are your dictionaries you can do: `diff = {}` `for key in d1: if key in d2: diff[key] = d1[key] - d2[key]`. You cannot substract dictionaries in the fashion you suggested, this nested fashion should be quick. The if statement is there to prevent a KeyError.

Comment: What if the key is in d1 but not in d2 ? Then the resulting dict would not have it. The idea is to subtract the values for the common keys and also preserve the keys which are present in d1 but not d2.

Comment: that is the purpose of the if statement in the code from my above comment @SaikatKumarDey. The code would only subtract if it was found in the dictionary. If there was no if statement there you could wrap the code in a try catch block and catch a KeyError

Comment: I meant, if the key is in d1 and d2 then we should subtract. What if the key is in d1 and not in d2? Due to the "if" statement, those keys won't show up in the resultant dictionary.

Comment: Well you can just add other conditional statements. Or you could make a list with all of the keys in both dictionaries and then have three conditional statements for if the key is in both dicts, or only one of the two. It really depends on implementation